# Connection to 5ghz network has no internet for supporting wireless card

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I just got a new wireless card for my Windows 10 desktop, the fenvi fv8801. [By other user accounts and product description](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R38R344Z61GS82/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewpnt?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00Y2DU8T4#R38R344Z61GS82) it supports 5ghz networks. My wireless router is the Linksys EA7400, again, 5ghz compatible. When I try to connect, I am able to get to the 2.4ghz network, but not the 5ghz network- it connects but says internet is not available. I suspect it's a driver or configuration issue as I can get the 5ghz from my phone and everything works.

I also have made sure the computer has all the drivers it needs. It appears the wireless card works on the Intel chipset and uses the standard Intel wireless drivers, so nothing spooky there.

I suspect that I am seeing some sort of strange holdover from the old wireless card- like it needs deleted or the drivers are still around or something. I noticed that in my Network Connections it's listed as Wi-Fi 2, but I can't rename it as just Wi-Fi because that one "already exists" however, I don't see anything with such a name as that in my list.

Anyone have any thoughts on troubleshooting this? Is my card just a lemon or something or is my configuration bogus?

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 58-91-CF-16-0C-42
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::20dd:6f47:1031:7541%8(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.114(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, September 19, 2017 7:36:03 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, September 20, 2017 7:24:16 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 190353871
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-46-CD-8E-60-A4-4C-5E-A8-6B
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: When you connect using 5.8GHz, do you get an IP? Does your wi-fi router show that your computer has connected?

Comment: @someuser Yes- to both of those questions.

Comment: Well, if you get an IP. What is the IP, subnet mask, default gateway and DNS IP? Can you ping the router's IP?

Comment: Your adapter/network being named "Wi-Fi 2" has nothing to do with your problem

Comment: @someuser See my above edit.

Comment: Are other devices able to connect to 5Ghz, and does the 5Ghz station appear in tools like InSSIDer? Also, in some cases, configuration for the 5Ghz network is separate from the 2Ghz, and may be disabled by default.

Comment: @KJ4IPS Yes, My phone, other laptop, etc. can all connect to the 5Ghz network. I see the 5Ghz item in inSSIDer. Good signal and all. I don't think anything's disabled as I can connect with other devices and my computer, it just doesn't have internet available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what the issue was, but I think it had something to do with the broadcasted channel that was being used by the router. In the wireless router settings, I changed the channel from "auto" to the highest one supported by my router "161 - 5.805 Ghz". I am guessing that it was either doing something stupid, or my card doesn't support certain lower channels.

Either way, setting it explicitly to that worked.

Comment: That is totally a thing, even though it should not be. I've heard of certain cards preferring specific channels. You can mark your own solution as the answer if this is solved.

Comment: @HackSlash Yup, I intend to, but the system won't let me for another 11 hours, though.

Comment: Maybe your card has a defective antenna that only works in the highest 5.8GHz frequency band. I would check the speed on the desktop and the signal strength on the router to verify.

Comment: @someuser thanks, I'll make sure to check that over

Answer (score 0):

I once had this problem and I had to go through 5 drivers until I found one that worked and the one that worked was not the newest driver.

Try getting one from the manufacturer:

http://en.fenvi.com/en/download_zx.php

Then compare performance to the driver from Intel and the driver from Microsoft.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following steps:

1. From your desktop, ping 192.168.1.1
2. If it pings, there is nothing wrong with your Wi-Fi adapter. Next step is to test DNS resolution, nslookup google.com
3. If it also resolves into IP, test your routing: ping 8.8.8.8
4. Assuming you can't ping 8.8.8.8, try tracert 8.8.8.8

2a. If you failed step 1, try arp

Comment: None of these steps have anything to do with WiFi, which exists on Layer 1. Ping and traceroute use layer 3 and ARP uses layer 2. You need to connect Layer 1 before you can use these commands.

Comment: And which layer does DHCP work? OP's desktop got an IP. OP's question is "thoughts on troubleshooting this". I am offering my help on troubleshooting. Not solution.

Comment: DHCP is technically a layer 7 protocol but the source address is 0.0.0.0 because layer 3 isn't even configured yet.

Comment: OP's desktop got an IP via DHCP. So I assume his layer 1 is working.

Comment: It's like you didn't read what his problem was.

Comment: more like your didn't read my comments.